# Submitting select menus

Tags: jquery, database, forms, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I use a code in jQuery Mobile to dynamically generate select menus, but I'm having trouble passing the data to the database.
The menus are generated using the `append` method for each form element. Here is a short code example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
var r = arr[i];
console.log(r);
    name    = r.optionname;
    val     = r.optionvalue;
    nameid  = r.optionnameid;
    valueid = r.optionvalueid;
if ($("#prodAttributes_"+prodID+" select").is("[name*=" + name + "]")) {

var select = $("#prodAttributes_"+prodID).find("select[name*=" + name + "]");
var option = $("<option></option>");
    option.val(val);
    option.text(val);
    option.attr("id", valueid);
    select.append(option);
  } else {

var select = $("<select></select>");
    select.attr("name", name);
    select.attr("id", nameid);
var option = $("<option></option>");
    option.val(val);
    option.text(val);
    option.attr("id", valueid);
    select.append(option);
var label = $("<label></label>");
    label.attr("class", "select");
    label.attr("for", name);


    label.text(name);
    fieldset.append(select);
    myform.append(div);
    $(myform).appendTo("#prodAttributes_"+prodID);

    }

    }
```

I'm aware it isn't the nicest code.

<strike>The problem I have is I don't know how to get the submitted data. 
 I'm so confused if I should use the form tag.</strike>

Is it really needed?  Should I use a *< button >* tag or use the *< input >* tag?

Should I use a function when clicking the submit, or should I use something out of jQuery's library?

Generated HTML here:

```
<div id="prodAttributes_2">
<form id="attributesubmit">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<div role="heading" >Options:</div>

<select name="Memory" id="4">
<option value="16 mb" id="3">16 mb</option>
<option value="32 mb" id="4">32 mb</option>
</select>


<select name="Model" id="3">
<option value="Premium" id="6">Premium</option>
<option value="Deluxe" id="7">Deluxe</option>
</select>

</fieldset>
</div>
<input type="button" id="submitme" value="send" />
</form>
</div>
```

[I also made a JSFiddle to show you how it actually looks](http://jsfiddle.net/whitehat/huRQF/).

I concluded that I should run a function. However, I doubt `serialize()` does what I want, so something like:

```
$("#submitme").live('click', function(){
$('select').each(function() {
var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');

alert('Value: ' + selectedOption.val() + ' Text: ' + selectedOption.text());
});

var formData = '<p>something generated</p>';
var newPage = $('<div data-role="page" data-url="test"><div data-role="header"><h1>test</h1></div><div data-role="content">'+formData+'</div></div');
    newPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );
    //append it to the page container
    $.mobile.changePage(newPage);

        });
```

But then I still require the name/ID of the selected element itself.
How would the code look when it would be ready to insert in a SQL database?

Comment: $("<option></option>") should just be $("option"). You don't need to include the whole tag in the selector.

Comment: thank you @Andbdrew, i knew that,but i was told that way is called shortcode,and not the "good way" , i confused bouth that aswell lol.

Comment: $("<option></option>") should just be $("<option>")

Answer (score 1):

That's entirely related with the action that you want to achieve. If you use a button `submit` when you do the click it's going to look for all the elements in the form and send it to the url of the attribute `action` of the `form` in the format `get` or `post` and that's it's automatic, so if you need to send a lot of elements you need to consider of use `submit`. Now remember that's not ajax so you couldn't know what's happens in the server. If are a few element's you can catch the click event of a button and wrap by selectors the elements and then send it by ajax.

**Note**

You can bind the `submit` event of the button type `submit` and then send an ajax called to control the response of the server

**UPDATE**

I'm not so sure what you want to accomplish but here's how you can get and handle all the fields in a form binding the submit button to avoid of doing selector for each html element in the form

Assuming that the button it's input submit

```
$('form#attributesubmit').live('submit', function (){

     $(this).serialize() -->> this give you all the fields and values of the form
});
```

Comment: and *ziesemer , i'm sorry i didnt mentioned that,however in jquery-mobile it sends me if use the action tag to the root page.I made a function : $("#submitme").live('click', function(){ for the button,it contains jquery-mobile's changePage.The database i use is webdb,it is used to localstorage,so i dont need a aditional action page.it is totaly clientside (for a phone app)

Comment: i have a simular function using serialize,however when use it only gives me the "text" results,and i cant update my database with text,it eats numbers lol.

Comment: the only thing that you need to know are which are numbers an parsing into the values that type that you need

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you need to have the data submitted back to the server.  You can either do this using AJAX (using additional jQuery methods) - which would optionally allow you to stay on the same page after clicking "Send", or you can do it as a traditional HTML form - which will require a `<form>` tag, with the `action` set to the URL you want to send to.